# Google Cloud Platform - App Engine - System Environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I am using Gitlab, Spring Boot and Google Cloud App Engine, Google Cloud mySql.

I have resource bundle files like application-{environment}.yaml for my Spring Boot application.

I don't want to keep the secrets in application-*.yaml files. I wanted those sensitive variables in App Engine's System Environment. But I think there is no Environment Variable support on Google Cloud App Engine.

I wanted to ask if there is a way to do this.. before I completely abandon Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Cloud [Secrets Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets) to store and retrieve them. That way you can keep serveless, as Google handles the [encryption](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/encryption) of secrets.